# Create SoupCookieJarText using full path to cookie

Tags: c++, c, webkit, gtk

I use webkitgtk to add features to wxWebview and I have got a problem. I can Add a filename to soup_cookie_jar_text_new but not full path to cookie. the library uses current working directory and I want to point to my directory. something like

```
SoupCookieJar* cookie = soup_cookie_jar_text_new("/path/to/cookies/cookie.txt", FALSE);//New cookie Jar to hold cookies
```

Is there a way to load cookiejar file from custom location?

Comment: Does the path '/path/to/cookies' exist?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry friends. There was something wrong with passing the path. So this line of code works perfectly!

```
SoupCookieJar* cookie = soup_cookie_jar_text_new("/path/to/cookies/cookie.txt", FALSE);
```